# Reseting yup field based on another variable's value (not included in the form object or yup schema)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

Currently, I'm using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) with [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup). My yup object is static and is working fine right now. But I need to change some fields' rules based on some actions in my app. For example, I want to change the *Max* value of the *Number* field dynamically based on a variable's change **which is not included in the form**. I want to know if it is possible or not. and If yes, I'd appreciate any hints, guides, links, or code samples.

#### Part of my yup schema:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape(
{
    ruleType: yup.string().required(errorMessages.required),
    address: yup.string().required(errorMessages.required),
    number: yup
        .string()
        .nullable()
        .required(errorMessages.required)
        .typeError(errorMessages.required)
        .when(['ruleType'], {
            is: (ruleType: string) => ruleType === 'collection',
            then: yup
                .string()
                .nullable()
                .test({
                    name: 'min',
                    exclusive: false,
                    params: {},
                    message: errorMessages.minNumber,
                    test: (value) => +value > 0,
                }),
            otherwise: yup
                .string()
                .nullable()
                .test({
                    name: 'min',
                    exclusive: false,
                    params: {},
                    message: 'Must be more than 0',
                    test: (value) => +value > 0 + 10 ** -18,
                }),
        }),
}
);
```

As you can see, since the *number* field is a string, I have to turn it into a number and check whether it is more than zero or not. But sometimes a variable of type number gets changed inside of my code and I want to assign its value as the *Max* value to my *number* field.
I'm not sure how can I reassign the max value of a field which is inside a static yup object. Below is my RHF setup:

```
const methods = useForm({
defaultValues,
shouldFocusError: false,
resolver: yupResolver(schema),
});
```

And I have a *state* in my code which gets changed based on some actions:

```
const [max, setMax] = useState(0);
```

And then this *max* variable should be assigned as the max value of the number field inside the yup object(schema).

Please consider that my yup object is much more complex than the one mentioned above and I'm also using a dynamic form (**[useFieldArray](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/)**). Not sure whether I explained well and provided enough explanation or not. But If it's needed, I can provide a CodeSandBox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realized that I can use [context](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/#context) which is one of the `useForm`'s *Schema validation props*. These are the steps that I took to get the code to work in the way I wanted:

#### Step 1: Passing my variable as context to my yup validation schema

As mentioned with the help of one of the `useForm's` schema validation props called context, I managed to pass my state to yup schema like below: (code is super simplified)

```js
// My State:
const [contextVariable, setContextVariable] = React.useState();
// useForm settings:
const methods = useForm<Type>({
    defaultValues,
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    context: {
        contextVariable, // Pass my variable to yup schema
    },
});
```

#### Step2: Update yup version:

I was not using the latest yup version. So with the help of the [migration guide](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1906), I managed to use the latest version and its new features.

#### Step3: Accessing the passed variable inside yup schema:

You can access any passed context variable inside the yup schema by using one of the [Schema.test(name: string, message: string | function | any, test: function): Schema](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema) OR [Schema.test(name: string, message: string | function | any, test: function): Schema](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema) functions that yup provides:

**Using `.when()`:**

```js
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    field1: yup.string(),
    field2: yup
        .string()
        .when(
            ['field1', '$contextVariable'], // Notice the $ sign!!!
            ([field1, contextVariable], schema) => {
                console.log(field1, contextVariable);
                                // And do your logic here with the available variables
                return schema.required(); // Or more complex rules
            }
        ),
});
```

**Using `.test()`:**

```js
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    field1: yup.string(),
    field2: yup
        .string()
        .test(
            'name',
            'message',
            // Must not be an arrow function in order to access this.options.context because yup binds to "this".
            function test(value, {path}) {
                const { contextVariable } = this.options.context;
                // And do your logic with the accessed variable context
                return true;
            }
        ),
});
```